# Adding childViewController does not include basic settings like background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage

Background: I am following Apple's example on making a iMessage app, where I am to present a `childViewController` (subclass `UIViewController`) to the `MSMessagesAppViewController`.

I am doing everything as basic as possible. In my `childViewController`, this is what I do in `viewWillAppear`

```
//ChildViewController.m

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; //! this does not show

    UILabel *middleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    middleLabel.text = @"this is the childView"; //! however, this shows up
    middleLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height*0.20);
    [self.view addSubview:middleLabel];

}
```

And then in my `MSMessagesAppViewController`, this is what I do in `willBecomeActiveWithConversation` (which is basically the same as `viewWillAppear`)

```
- (void)willBecomeActiveWithConversation:(MSConversation *)conversation
{
     [super willBecomeActiveWithConversation:conversation];
     UIViewController *viewController;
     viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainInterface" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childViewController"];
     [self addChildViewController:viewController];


     viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
     viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
     viewController.view.center = self.view.center;
     [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

     [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

As you can see, nothing special, and yet the issue I am running is the background **will not become yellow colored**, although I set it in my childViewController.

**Edit**

Additional tests show that gesture recognizers in the `ChildViewController` also somehow becomes disabled, and the same with `UIButton`s.

For those curious, the source code is on [Github](https://github.com/zallanx/iMessageTestApp).

Comment: you are share your screen shot?

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya added a screenshot as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key reason here is the code below:

```
viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
viewController.view.center = self.view.center;
```

For some reasons, it is not correct.

1. The bounds of `self.view` will change, it will not always be the previous `self.view.bounds`. The frame of the view of your childViewController will not be `self.view.bounds`.
2. Since 1 is not correct, `viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` and  `viewController.view.center = self.view.center;` will make something even worse. Your view of the child view controller will not be at the position as you think.
3. If you do not understand, you can try delete `viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` and `viewController.view.center = self.view.center;` and set some other frame to `viewController.view.frame` to test it.
4. Gesture recognizers are disabled is in the same reason that you set a wrong frame.

Useless codes:

```
viewController.view.center = self.view.center;
```

If `viewController.view.frame == self.view.bounds`, it is useless to set their center equal. CGRect actual determines the center of a position.

Solution:

Use auto layout to set the position of `viewController.view` or get the actual frame of your views frame.

Comment: This was precisely the issue. Thank you for the indepth explanation as well!

Answer (score 0):

replace your code to this:

```
- (void)willBecomeActiveWithConversation:(MSConversation *)conversation
{
   [super willBecomeActiveWithConversation:conversation];
   UIViewController *viewController;
   viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainInterface" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childViewController"];
   [self addChildViewController:viewController];


   viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
   viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   viewController.view.center = self.view.center;
   viewController.view = [UIColor yellowColor];
   [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

   [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

Comment: While I could definitely make the change in my `MSMessagesAppViewController`, my goal is to have all the view logic be put in my childViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line : [self addChildViewController:viewController];

Before        : [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

Comment: Unfortunately changing the placement did not result in any changes

Answer (score 0):

viewController.view.frame could be wrong or zero, and the label is showing because it's size is absolute and it has overflown the superview.